# how to configure Consumer_run for async.operations.all?

Tags: configuration, crontab, magento-cron, system.log

I have enabled my custom modules for certain functionality, successfully deployed but magento2 admin portal prompts me "something went wrong" when I click my newly installed module.(the module is not working)

I headed to system.log and I found this,  which are responsible to the error

```
> main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required
> connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp []
> []
```

Update

I check (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/mq/manage-message-queues.html)
And I m required to add external MQ, thus I followed the guide by adding  line below to my magentoroot/app/etc/env.php

```
>   'cron_consumers_runner' => array(
>         'cron_run' => false,
>         'max_messages' => 20000,
>         'consumers' => array(
>             'async.operations.all',
>         )
>     ),
```

I believe i need to somehow include this  'async.operations.all' as consumers.It displayed in my bin/magento consumer:list,yet it still not working ,what did I miss here?

tried re-upgrade ,compile & deploy with sudo chmod -777 on var/www/html and clearing cache.

Update 
On magentoroot/vendor/magento/module-webapi-async/etc/queue_consumer.xml

```
> <?xml version="1.0"?> <!-- /**  * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights
> reserved.  * See COPYING.txt for license details.  */
> --> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/consumer.xsd">
>     <consumer name="async.operations.all" queue="async.operations.all" connection="cron_consumers_runner"
>               consumerInstance="Magento\AsynchronousOperations\Model\MassConsumer"/>
> </config>
```

& queue_topology.xml

```
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/topology.xsd">
>     <exchange name="magento" type="topic" connection="cron_consumers_runner">
>         <binding id="async.operations.all" topic="async.#" destinationType="queue" destination="async.operations.all"/>
>     </exchange> </config>
```

With both updated on connection with 'db' or 'cron_consumers_runner'.I do compile and clear cache, headed to the admin portal.S till the same (Attention, Something went wrong, module not working).

I head back to system.log, now there is no error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Check `app/etc/env.php`. You may be missing the connection configuration.

Add the following element to array in app/etc/env.php:

```
'queue' => [
    'amqp' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '5672',
        'user' => 'guest',
        'password' => 'guest',
        'virtualhost' => '/',
        'ssl' => ''
    ]
]
```

This is just a sample code, you have to modify it according to your requirement.

**UPDATE**

There are two ways to configure Message Queues in Magento2.

One is using RabbitMQ, if you are using RabbitMQ, then you need to connect to the RabbitMQ server. Above code is for that connection.

Second is using Database and cron, if you are using this setup you need configuration as mentioned at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/mq/manage-message-queues.html

**UPDATE 2**

Check if the connection name in XML files and env.php are same.

Comment: I m using CE version ,and what does this does?and do i need to include job name from my custom module's crontab.xml?

Comment: @EdTan There are two ways to configure Message Queues in Magento2. One is using RabbitMQ, if you are using RabbitMQ, then you need to connect to the RabbitMQ server. Above code is for that connection. Second is using Database and cron, if you are using this setup you need configuration as mentioned at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/mq/manage-message-queues.html

Comment: would you help me with method 2?

Comment: @EdTan share your xml files.

Comment: updated ,check it out

Comment: somehow I found a very similar situation (https://github.com/magento/bulk-api-ce/pull/29/files) but I m not sure how does the fix would help me in any way.

Comment: @EdTan Replace connection="amqp" in xml files with connection="cron_consumers_runner" and check

Comment: which xml are you refering?

Comment: tried on both ,does't work

Comment: @EdTan Change on all the XML files and run setup:upgrade and try

Comment: i tried update both of the xml from module-webapi-async/etc ,and then compile .go back to portal .Same error and module is cannot be used .And system.log doesn't not state any error anymore .I also tried change ampq to db,same result as cron_consumers_runners.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable in Magento Cloud to configure the RabbitMQ.

[image]

Login to Magento server and then run the command

```
php -r 'print_r(json_decode(base64_decode($_ENV["MAGENTO_CLOUD_RELATIONSHIPS"])));
```

This command will give you the details of all the services running in Magento Cloud with its credentials. Copy the username, password, and virtual host for RabbitMq and add those details.