# Changing config/connection type for consumers

Tags: xml, routing

I would like to set this consumers: 'async.operations.all' connection type from rabbitmq (amqp) to crontab+sql (message queue & mysqlmq)as default so my setup of external crontab can execute .

[how to configure Consumer_run for async.operations.all?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272164/how-to-configure-consumer-run-for-async-operations-all)

Answer (score 0):

Only RabbitMQ is efficient enough message broker for the `async.operations.all` consumer. Others will simply not work.

This specifically applies to this consumer, which is required for the Bulk API feature. If you don't use it (and high chances are that you don't need it), you can disable it:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_WebapiAsync
```

If you *do* want to run `async.operations.all`, then you *have to* configure RabbitMQ, e.g. as detailed in this [guide for CentOS/RHEL 7, 8](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/how-to-fix-consumer-async-operations-all-skipped-as-required-connection-amqp-is-not-configured-unknown-connection-name-amqp-in-magento-2).